# on input javascript validation is working only in last one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

If it is a common question please don't mind. I am a beginner in javascript.
I have wrote a JavaScript code to compare equality of each form with each ans saved in database. but when I am running the code it only checks the last one. and others shows as not matched. I want it to work in every form and compare it with relative answer database column.
code goes here.......

```html
<h1>Listing questions</h1>

<div align="center">
<table class="table table-bordered" style="width:30%" bgcolor="#00FF00" >
  <thead>
   
  <tbody >
    <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= form_for question do |f| %>
    
    <tr>
        <td><%= question.q1 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans1, :id=>"ans1" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a1, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><%= question.q2 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans2, :id=>"ans2" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a2, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%= question.q3 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans3, :id=>"ans3" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a3, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td>      
    </tr>
        
     <tr>
        <td><%= question.q4 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans4, :id=>"ans4" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a4, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><%= question.q5 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans5, :id=>"ans5" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a5, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><%= question.q6 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans6, :id=>"ans6" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a6, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><%= question.q7 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans7, :id=>"ans7" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a7, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><%= question.q8 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans8, :id=>"ans8" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a8, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td><%= question.q9 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans9, :id=>"ans9" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a9, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>

     <tr>
      <td><%= question.q10 %></td> 
        <td>=</td> <%= f.hidden_field :ans10, :id=>"ans10" %>       
        <td><%= f.text_field :a10, :oninput => "check(this)" %> </td> 
    </tr>
        <%end%>  
       
      </tr>
    <% end %> 

  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= will_paginate @questions, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
              function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans1').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans2').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans3').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans4').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans5').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans6').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans7').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans8').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans9').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }
                function check(input) {
                if (input.value != document.getElementById('ans10').value) {
                     input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
                     $("p").hide();
                 } else {
                    // input is valid -- reset the error message
                    input.setCustomValidity('');
                  }
               }

            </script>
```

Comment: Parsed HTML would make more sense..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Many declarations of `function check` will override all previous declarations of the function. Only last `function check()` will work.

Use only one function declarations and `test` input values in that handler.

`$(input).parents('tr').find(':input:hidden')` will return hidden element in specific `tr`

Try this:

```js
function check(input) {
  var pre = $(input).parents('tr').find(':input:hidden')
  if (input.value != pre.val()) {
    input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
    $("p").hide();
  } else {
    input.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
```